# How to choose a parent based on a decedent using CSS

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to choose a parent if it has a decendent of class 'foo'.
Is this possible using CSS..?

In the following example, I would want to choose parent (having class='B') as it has a descendent of 'foo'.

```
<parent class='A'>
    <child>
        <grand-child>
        <grand-child class='boo'>
    </child>
</parent>

<parent class='B'>
    <child>
        <grand-child>
        <grand-child class='foo'>
    </child>
</parent>
```

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/7874193)

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is "no".  See https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/ and https://css-tricks.com/a-use-case-for-a-parent-selector/

Comment: The general answer is no, but for some styling, such as changing background, or at least giving that visual appearance, it may be possible. What style you are trying to change?